# Checking for empty number as input

Tags: python

Consider this code:

```
>>> num = int(raw_input('Enter the number > '))
```

If the user types nothing and presses 'Enter', I want to capture that. (Capture an empty input)

There are two ways of doing it:

- I do a simple `num = raw_input()`, then check whether `num == ''`. Afterwards, I can cast it to a `int`.
- I catch a `ValueError`. But in that case, I can't differentiate between an non-numerical input and a empty input.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What do you want to happen upon empty input? Set `num` to some default value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
num = 42 # or whatever default you want to use
while True:
    try:
        num = int(raw_input('Enter the number > ') or num)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print 'Invalid number; please try again'
```

This relies on the fact that `int()` applied to a number will simply return that number, and that the emtpy string evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
flag = True
while flag:
    try:
       value = input(message)
    except SyntaxError:
        value = None
    if value is None: 
        print "Blank value. Enter floating point number"
```

For blank values with input this can catch the exception and alert the user with the print statement